# Fill a range with a specific value in a cell until the next value is reached till the last row

Tags: excel, vba

This is one of my first VBA codes and really appreciate any help with the below query.

I am trying to format the data loaded from a text file with repetitive information.

I want to add a new column, and copy the number against 'Account num' to fill the range until the next 'Account num' is found. I also want to keep the first row as headers and delete all other 'Account num' rows and unwanted rows (not added in the query).

I have managed to create a new column and add the header but not sure what is wrong with the below code to perform rest of my actions.

Sample excel data :

```
  
Account num Date    Code
    Account num 41008
    01/01/2023  1234567
    01/01/2023  1234568
    01/01/2023  1234569
    01/01/2023  1234570
    01/01/2023  1234571
    01/01/2023  1234572
    Account num 41008
    Account num 42008
    01/01/2023  1234567
    Date    Code
    01/01/2023  1234572
    01/01/2023  1234573
    01/01/2023  1234574
    01/01/2023  1234575
    01/01/2023  1234576
    Account num 42008
```

```
Sub insertcol()
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Value = "Account num"
End Sub
```

```
Sub fillRange()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("test") 
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = ws.Range("C1:C" & lRow)

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel.Value Like "4*" Then
       cel.Offset(0, -2).Value = cel.Value
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

```
Desired output:

Account num Date    Code
41008   01/01/2023  1234567
41008   01/01/2023  1234568
41008   01/01/2023  1234569
41008   01/01/2023  1234570
41008   01/01/2023  1234571
41008   01/01/2023  1234572
42008   01/01/2023  1234567
42008   01/01/2023  1234572
42008   01/01/2023  1234573
42008   01/01/2023  1234574
42008   01/01/2023  1234575
42008   01/01/2023  1234576
```

Comment: What's to happen with the Account num 41008? To be ignored since it doesn't have a date/code following it? Suppose that's an "unwanted row" now that I reread your intro.

Comment: Your sample data is in 1 column, will your data be separated in 3 columns prior to running the code?

Comment: Hi @Notus_Panda, yes, Account num 41008 will become an unwanted row. To answer your second question, the data is already in 3 columns - guess it got confusing because of the alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your actual data has a fix pattern as seen in your sample data. Anyway, if yes then another way is by filtering the column which contain "account num". But please note, Mr. Notus_Panda's code is much much faster.

Before running the sub: (please ignore the fill color)
[image]

The code assume that the fix pattern of the data is something like this :
Each group will be enclosed with the same account num, (in sample data : yellow, orange and blue).
There will always two same account number, never more than two same account number, never only one account number. The last row data in column A is always the same with the last row data in column B.

As seen in sample data, B2 and B9 has the same value, which is 41008 (yellow),
and B10 and B18 has the same value which is 42008 (orange), also the one in blue has two "51001"

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range, rgAcc As Range, i As Integer
Dim c1 as Range, c2 as Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheet1
    .Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    .Range("A1").Value = "Account num"
    Set rg = .Range("B1", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

rg.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=account num"
Set rgAcc = rg(1, 2).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlVisible)

    i = 1
    For Each cell In rgAcc
        If i = 1 Then Set c1 = cell Else Set c2 = cell
        i = i + 1
        If i = 3 Then Range(c1.Offset(1, -2), c2.Offset(-1, -2)).Value = cell.Value: i = 1
    Next

    With rg
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("account num", "date"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter Field:=1
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

First, the sub do the same thing as yours, which is insert a column for "Account Num" header in column A.

Then it create rg variable from cell B1 to column C whatever lastrow with data, filter the rg with "account num" and then set rgAcc as the range of the visible cells of column CODE.

Then it loop to each cell in rgAcc, create two range variable of the looped cell as c1 if i = 1 and c2 if i=2. By the time the i value is 3, it reset i to 1 and fill column A (which row is in between c1 row and c2 row) with the looped cell value.

Finally it filter column B with two criteria which is "account num" and "date", then delete the row.

The sub cannot be run if column B "account num" and "date" text is not fix. For example, in one cell the value is "account num", another cell value is "account number" ... one cell value is "date", another cell value is "date blablabla".

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @karma - it worked perfectly. Yes, the format is the same and the headers will not change as its a downloaded report.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I knew about using arrays before looping through ranges and the such to save time especially if you're working with bigger files which yours looks like it could be. So that's why I try to let newcomers know about them and their speed from the get-go:

```
Sub fillRange()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("test")
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim SrchRng As Range, i As Long, arr(), arrP()
    Dim currentAcc As Long, rCount As Long
    
    Set SrchRng = ws.Range("A2:C" & lRow) 'headerrow can remain as is
    arr = SrchRng.Value
    ReDim arrP(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To UBound(arr, 2)) 'UBound(arr,1) = how many "rows" in the array, UBound(arr,2) = how many "columns"
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) ' it is slower to iterate over cells/ranges than to work with arrays
        If arr(i, 3) Like "4*" Then
            currentAcc = arr(i, 3) 'arr(i,3) means the i+1'th (header including) row the third column
        End If
        If IsDate(arr(i, 2)) Then 'we want to skip the "Date Code" line as well in your example
            rCount = rCount + 1 'we use rCount since we want to skip the unnecessary rows
            arrP(rCount, 1) = currentAcc
            arrP(rCount, 2) = arr(i, 2)
            arrP(rCount, 3) = arr(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
    
    ws.Range("A2:C" & rCount + 1).Value = arrP
    ws.Range("A" & rCount + 1 & ":C" & lRow).Offset(1, 0).Delete 'delete what's left
End Sub
```

I started off with this setup:
[image: start]
The array makes it so the VBE doesn't need to interact as much with Excel (that's usually what slows it down)

**Edit:**

This should accommodate for more columns:

```
Sub fillRange()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("test")
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim SrchRng As Range, i As Long, arr(), arrP()
    Dim currentAcc As Long, rCount As Long
    Dim lCol As Long: lCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Set SrchRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)) 'headerrow can remain as is
    arr = SrchRng.Value
    ReDim arrP(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To UBound(arr, 2)) 'UBound(arr,1) = how many "rows" in the array, UBound(arr,2) = how many "columns"
    
    Dim j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) ' it is slower to iterate over cells/ranges than to work with arrays
        If arr(i, 3) Like "4*" Then
            currentAcc = arr(i, 3) 'arr(i,3) means the i+1'th (header including) row the third column
        End If
        If IsDate(arr(i, 2)) Then 'we want to skip the "Date Code" line as well in your example
            rCount = rCount + 1 'we use rCount since we want to skip the unnecessary rows
            arrP(rCount, 1) = currentAcc
            For j = 2 To lCol
                arrP(rCount, j) = arr(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    With ws
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(rCount + 1, lCol)).Value = arrP
        .Range(.Cells(rCount + 1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Offset(1, 0).Delete 'delete what's left
    End With
End Sub
```

This is how it looks like: [image: edited result]

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Hi @Notus_Panda Thank you so much for spending time on this. Its my fist time using arrays and its taking a bit of time for me to understand this. Few questions    1. For some reason my last row is getting deleted. 2. If I want to increase my range to include more existing columns after Account_num, Date, and code (example value, currency etc) while I perform the same actions, what should I do? The text file is basically a report  from the system which has multiple pages and for each new page, the header row repeats.

Comment: You're welcome. About your first question, I don't know why your last row is getting deleted, unless you mean the Account num 42008 which I thought should be deleted? See my edit for data -> result, if this is not how you wanted it, let me know. As for your second question, I included another for loop to include the variability of your columns (with lCol). Ofc the first column is special so we keep that one out of it, the rest is just the same value so it's easier to use `arrP(rCount,j) = arr(i,j)` there.